# az pipeline embedded ampersand (&) breaks when passing key=value

Tags: azure-devops, powershell-4.0, azure-cli2

How to pass a value that has ampersand (&) and possibly other characters.  the following powershell script fails

```
 $groupname = "owtest"
 $tags = @()
 $key="test"
 $value="some=&this&that"
 $tags += "$key=$value"
 $creation = az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupname --variables $tags --only-show-errors
```

Is there a workaround to allow the ampersand embedded character?

Comment: Try `$value='some=&this&that'` instead of `$value="some=&this&that"`, will it work?

Comment: You can `Write-host $tags` to check how your final '$tags' would be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my test, we must use **double quotes**(**single quotes** can't work for this scenario) for value which contains `&` or other characters. So if you pass variables directly to final command, it should be:

```
az pipelines variable-group create --name $groupname --variables test="some=&this&that" ...
```

And if you want to use the format above(`$tags += "$key=$value"`), you need to
use `$value="""some=&this&that"""` instead of `$value="some=&this&that"`.

Comment: This doesn't work for me with "az pipelines variable-group variable create". I have to enclose each "&" with double quotes, and the entire variable with single quotes, as described here: https://tomssl.com/setting-keyvault-secrets-through-the-azure-cli/ ... But what if there are quotes in the value!? This is crazy, and really needs guidelines documented.

Comment: This is also true for setting passwords as secrets (not KeyVault) using variable groups. Was having issues with a password that contains quotes, even when typing it from the UI. Double quotes did the trick although it does seem wrong that way